# DB saving date without time, postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql, momentjs

I am trying to save date and time into postgres db, which has only two data types to store such value - timestamp and date (date does not store time tho)
First, I am getting current date and then concatenating it with the time I screape from website

```
var date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var dateTime = date.toString().concat(" " + time);
    var finalDate = moment(dateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

This creates value like this

```
2020-08-04 05:30:00
```

But when I execute this query

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO Playback (PlaybackDateTime, SongID, RadioID) 
           VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`;
var values = [finalDate, songID, radioID]
```

There wont be no time in the database

```
2020-08-03 00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: How exactly are you reading the value from the database?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `create table` statement for `Playback`.

Comment: If the value you show from the database is the same as the one you entered from the Javascript then I guessing you are seeing time zone differences. I'm also going to guess that somewhere the time zone 'Asia/Kolkata` is involved. In addition to the questions asked above:  What is the time zone in the database(in psql ```show timezone```) also where the Javascript is running?